# Is it possible to integrate a clickable cell to vutify v-data-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Good morning,

I know that

```js
<v-data-table
    :headers="headersfav"
    :items="itemsfav"
    @click:row="showSaleslead"
>
```

can start an action when the row is clicked. Is there also the possibility to limit it to one cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no event to do that [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#events), but you could achieve that using item slot :

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headersfav" :items="itemsfav">
  <template v-slot:item.saleslead="{ item }">
    <span @click.stop="showSaleslead">{{ item.saleslead}}</span>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the relevant cell slot:

```html
<v-data-table
    :headers="headersfav"
    :items="itemsfav"
    @click:row="showSaleslead"
>
  <template slot="items.cellName" slot-scope="{item}">
    <div @click.stop="onSingleCellClick">{{ item.value }}</div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```